Postgresql creating a function to update a field with a subset of another
When adding new data to an existing table, I am trying to populate an existing field with a subset of data from another field. I'm using PGAdmin on postgres version 9 with postGIS extension
To achieve this I'm trying to create a function and trigger. This is what I have but I cant get it to run correctly - I'm getting syntax errors but not sure where.
The function is
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION update_tp_tag_field()
   RETURNS TRIGGER as $$
   BEGIN
   SET NEW."telco pole tag" = RIGHT((NEW."structure name"), STRPOS(REVERSE(NEW."structure name"),':')-1);
   RETURN NEW;
   END;
   $$ language sql;


and the trigger is:
CREATE TRIGGER populate_tp_tag_field
   BEFORE INSERT on data.PIA_Point_Structures
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE FUNCTION update_tp_tag_field();


The trigger saved ok, but the function gives a syntax error:
ERROR: syntax error at or near "CREATE" LINE 6: AS
$BODY$CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION update_tp_tag_field()
or if added from scratch I get:
ERROR: SQL functions cannot return type trigger
SQL state: 42P13
I tried a less complex function to try and identify some of the syntax errors:
BEGIN
NEW."telco pole tag" = "structure name";
RETURN NEW;

and although that was accepted, it didnt produce any results in the field at all. Any help getting this to work would be appreciated

Syntax errors usually point at the location where parser failed to understand the syntax. Please attach the message with the hint. The message you showed doesn't correspond to the code you showed. Also, what you claim worked fine, shouldn't - there's an unmatched, trailing single quote instead of a semicolon, and the text constant uses the double quotes instead of single quotes.

main body updated, there was a typo in the simplified code where the single quote should have been a semi colon. Additional error message added. The first error was when trying to edit an existing function. the second when I tried adding the function from new

Change language sql to language plpgsql to get rid of the SQL functions cannot return type trigger error.

Managed to solve it, it turns out there were two issues
the 1st was solved by Zegarek in the comments - I needed to change the language to PLPGSQL and that got rid of one error.
The second error is to do with the fact that I have more than one schema so needed to ensure the correct schema is referenced in both the function and trigger:
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION data.update_tp_tag_field()
RETURNS TRIGGER as $$
BEGIN
NEW."telco pole tag" = RIGHT(NEW."structure name", 
STRPOS(REVERSE(NEW."structure name"),':')-1);
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;

and
CREATE TRIGGER populate_tp_tag_field
BEFORE INSERT
ON data.pia_point_structures
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION data.update_tp_tag_field();

